# The relationship between @Component and @SpringView

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an error:

> Error creating bean with name 'personpresenter': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'personviewImpl'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'viewCache': Scope 'vaadin-ui' is not active
>   for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean
>   if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No VaadinSession bound to current
>   thread

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KmYuvGOq0ROmyA8OMxdmIHHtBte6BsVu/view)

Sorry I do not know how to insert the code should be thanks to Google driver to transfer code project you want to be dedicated and this is

Comment: Please paste your code into the question. Also, what version of Vaadin are you on?

Answer (score 0):

@SpringView
@Component
belong to the same class?

Because when I delete one of the two, the project started but does not show anything